# reCAPTCHA: No longer ever get single click resolution

Tags: recaptcha

When the "click once to prove you're not a robot" feature showed up, it was great. I loved skipping the captcha process by just clicking in the box. Sometimes, if I was using a site that used captcha with high frequency in a short time, it would hit me with selecting all the cars, or what have you.

I am now to the point where it will always make me identify cars/rivers/signs at least twice on any site that uses reCAPTCHA. It has been months since I've been able to click once on the box and be good to go when using my home computer.

What causes this? Is there some way I can "reset" so it gives me the more lenient captchas again? It's gotten quite aggravating.

Answer (score 3):

The reCaptcha "I'm not a robot" leniency algorithm/functionality depends on a few factors- such as ISP, time needed to click the checkbox upon revealing the form/loading the page, etc.  See The reCAPTCHA thread here for a good summary:  https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/425wos/eli5_how_do_those_checkbox_im_not_a_robot_capchas/

More than likely, you've become so familiar with the sites in question that you know immediately where to look for the reCaptcha checkbox and check the "I'm not a Robot" option.